# standard deviation for a sample from a uniform distribution?

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution, standard-deviation, sampling

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample from $U(0,1)$. I need to find the standard deviation of $max${$X_1,X_2,...,X_n$}. I am not sure how to begin with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You begin the problem by identifying the distribution's CDF.

$$\mathsf P(\max\limits_{i=1}^n \{X_i\} \leq x) = \mathsf P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (X_i\leq x))$$

Then you use the fact that for any surely non-negative continuous random variable $$\mathsf E(Y)=\int_0^\infty \mathsf P(Y>y)\operatorname d y$$

To find $\mathsf{Var}(\max \{X_i\}) = \mathsf E\Big(\big(\max \{X_i\}\big)^2\Big)-\Big(\mathsf E\big(\max \{X_i\}\big)\Big)^2$

Comment: I followed this method and came up with a variance of $((b-a)^2)/12$, which is the same with variance of $U(0,1)$, is this correct?

Comment: @VictorP.: That doesn't seem like it could be right.  Shouldn't there be a dependence on $n$?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, there clearly should. Did you use $\mathsf P(Y>y) = (1-y^n)~\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;1)}\;+\mathbf 1_{y\leqslant 0}$, and $\mathsf P(Y^2>z)=(1−z^{n/2})\mathbf 1_{z\in (0;1)}\;+\mathbf 1_{z\leqslant 0}$ ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp: If you're asking me, I haven't done anything on this problem today.  I remember it being a HW problem in school, though.

Comment: Right.  @VictorP.  Have *you* tried that?